# How to position the map div under form field?

Tags: html, css, forms

So this is the how the page looks, I would love to place the map below the coordinates field in the form? I am bit new to the styling so can you guys please help me achieve this. The raw source from the webpage has been pasted below in the [js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/arcv8eLz/2/).

```
<div>
    <p class="hilite">Example of code</p>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="hilite">More example of code</span>
</div>

.hilite {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This above code is just dummy code to post this question with a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the absolute positioning from your map and give it some height:

https://jsfiddle.net/Sixtus78/wvpc9mt3/3/

```
<style>
#mapDiv {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: grey;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. I will say this "You came like a god in time of need"

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

To shift the map below the coordinate field remove the following css from the `#mapDiv`

```
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 30%;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 5%;
  left: 60%;
```

and just add the css

```
#mapDiv {
height: 300px;
width :300px;
}
```

Because of `position:absolute` and other properties like `top`,`left` it was not working.

Hope this might help you.